# How to add Id and Name tags to JSP text field string

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a JSP string text field and I don't know if it would be possible to add an Id or Name tags on it. I have this:

```
<%data.printPasswordField(out,Customer.FIELD_PASSWORD,"text",100,0);%>
```

Is it possible that I can add the tags that I need on it?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you use "Scriptlets" in JSP?

Comment: Hi Sazzadur, I would like to know just if it is possible to add the ID or name tags on that string, and if so that I guess it is, how? Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet and the description with with is not informative enough to help you! e.g. what is `data` object in your code?

Comment: need more information. What are you trying to do?